# Managing TV show archives

Tags: database, archiving

My brother is a video editor for a automotive review show, and he has asked me for help in developing a way to organize their video archives, which contains about 2000 old shows.  Here's the scenario:

An intern watches the old shows and writes down information that includes the original air date, show number, and segments.  The segments themselves have several attributes, which include name, host(s), and car(s) shown.  The cars also have attributes, including price, color, and any performance statistics.

Each show currently has its own page in a binder, which is non-ideal.  He would really like to have a way to enter this information into a searchable (and hopefully even sortable) database.

He knows he could just throw together a word document with a table for each show, but obviously there's got to be a better way to do this.  Excel might be an option, but it also seems a bit limited.  If I remembered enough about programming, I'm confident I could put together a Java-based storage system with a simple GUI that stores shows, segments, and cars as objects.

That being said, is there any software available that could easily do this?  It is important that the software be fairly user friendly, as most of the people using it will be interns.

Comment: Is this for single-user access, running on a single computer, perhaps with read-only copies on others’ computers, but only a single computer making updates to the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a relational database.  For "basic user" friendliness I would start with MS Access.  If you want to use something that is more programmer friendly start with MySQL.

You will find that there are many options out there for relational database, so to choose the road you are going to travel, look ahead at the places you might want to go with the final data product.

In other words, if your application is going to be web based, choose a DB that you can easily integrate in to your web app.